# SOQL to find out list of Cases associated with XYZ entitlement Process?

Tags: soql, entitlements

How can I get the list of Cases associated with the XYZ milestone name ?

The below SOQL giving me only 1 records, but there could be 100 of such cases.

```
SELECT AccountId, Name 
FROM Entitlement 
WHERE SlaProcessId IN (
    SELECT Id 
    From SlaProcess 
    Where Name IN ('My Resolution Time'))
```

Comment: There could be or there is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CaseMilestone` object described here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_casemilestone.htm

Your query would be something like:

```
SELECT CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Id IN (SELECT CaseId FROM CaseMilestone WHERE MilestoneType.Name = 'XYZ Milestone')
```

Comment: How we findout the Name of the Entitlement Process?

Comment: I am not familiar with Entitlements.  You might have to get the Entitlement record using the AccountId from the Case, then get the SlaProcess record from that.